# Why difference between structure variable is always giving 16bytes in 64 bit OS?

Tags: c, struct, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct std
  {
  char c;
  char e;
};

void main()
  {
  struct std p,q;
  int start,last;
  last= &q;
  start= &p;
  printf("Size:%u %u Address_Diff:%d \n",&p, &q,(last-start) );
}
```

I am learning structure alignment and padding while we executing above program every time difference between two structure variables showing 16 bytes. I am not understanding why the difference is 16 bytes but i'm expecting the difference is 2 bytes.

some examples:

4077309424 4077309440 diff:16

3600238672 3600238688 diff:16

3272011008 3272011024 diff:16

Comment: Because the size of the padded struct is 16 bytes (each single byte is padded with additional 7).

Comment: @EugeneSh. The struct shown here is in all likelyhood not padded in any shape of form, and its size is 2, at least on all common platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Generally compiler may pad bytes, to keep each structure variable start position to word or double-word alignment. I guess the choice of alignment position may be architecture and compiler dependent.

It seems your compiler is keeping 16-byte alignment for each structure variable. Sometimes compiler may pad bytes to elements of structure to keep word or double-word alignment. You can check where the bytes padding happening, I mean bytes or padded at element level or structure level.

Do print each element address (as below) and see the difference between them.

```
printf("Size:%u %u Address_Diff:%d \n",&p.c, &p.e);
```

If difference is just one byte, it means that bytes are padded at structure level i.e., at the end of structure.